# How to solve a quadratic equation times the unknown index?

Tags: logarithms

$$
e^{-\lambda}*(1+\lambda+\lambda^2/2) = 7/12
$$

I am trying to figure out how to solve it. The answer is ~2.3, can I solve it without trying and error? If yes, how about higher order equation like this?

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no closed form for this solution.

Comment: Why is that? May I have some explanation on this? Thank you. @TheSilverDoe

Comment: @TheSilverDoe. There is a solution in terms of the generalized Lambert function.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, we will again have the same debate about is this or not considered as a closed form :)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe. I wrote this comment hoping that you will remember this debate. Cheers :-)

Comment: @tung. Forget it and use Newton method.

Comment: There is no analytic solution.  *Mathematica* gives (numerically) $2.34807$.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an analytical solution, I fear there's none, meaning that you must use a numerical method.

For that, I've simply re-written your equation as:

$$\lambda = \ln(\frac{12}{7} \cdot (1+\lambda+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}))$$

You start with a random value (I started with 1), and you create the following series:

$$\lambda_{n+1} = \ln(\frac{12}{7} \cdot (1+\lambda_n+\frac{\lambda_n^2}{2}))$$

These are the values you'll get (using MS-Excel):

| $i$ | $\lambda_i$ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1.455287233 |
| 3 | 1.79581344 |
| 4 | 2.022482542 |
| 5 | 2.161883637 |
| 6 | 2.243518034 |
| 7 | 2.289969499 |
| 8 | 2.315972168 |
| 9 | 2.33039519 |
| 10 | 2.338354703 |
| 11 | 2.342734945 |
| 12 | 2.345141739 |
| 13 | 2.34646307 |
| 14 | 2.347188142 |
| 15 | 2.34758592 |
| 16 | 2.347804112 |
| 17 | 2.347923787 |
| 18 | 2.347989424 |
| 19 | 2.348025423 |
| 20 | 2.348045166 |

Comment: Using $1$ as the initial guess, four iterations of Newton method give six significant figures.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the OP is solving a statistical equation. We convert to a [gamma regularized](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Gammaregularized) form:

$$e^{-\lambda}(1+\lambda+\lambda^2/2) =Q(3,x)=\frac7{12}\implies \lambda=Q^{-1}\left(3,\frac7{12}\right)$$

and apply [inverse gamma regularized](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=InverseGammaRegularized) as [shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inversegammaregularized%283%2C7%2F12%29). This is a [chi square](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=quantile+chi+square+distribution) related distribution quantile of $3$ degrees of freedom. For higher order equations:

$$e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^{a-1}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}=x\implies \lambda=Q^{-1}(a,x);0\le x\le1$$